# How to make Terminal app tab labels static?

Tags: terminal, macos

I'd like to have arbitrary labels that i create for each Terminal tab static. No matter what is going on inside terminal tab. Something like this:

[image: my tab labels]

But Terminal app keeps it changing on some events...

Is there some setting to prevent these changes?

Comment: Terminal > Preferences… > Profiles > (Select your Profile) > Window > Title and …(Select your Profile) > Tab > Title are the two areas that govern the settings of your query. Also click on Escape sequences… in each section, as an example on the Tab tab, there are two Escape sequences… links and both show different content. Correctly manipulating these settings and using the information in the Escape sequences… links should get you what you want.